# Byte representation of float as integer equation

Tags: math, floating-point, interpretation

In [this](http://www.machinedlearnings.com/2011/06/fast-approximate-logarithm-exponential.html) article an equation is used I don't understand:

- **I = (e + B) * L + m * L**

**I** is the byte representation of a float interpreted as an integer.
Here is an example:

```
float x = 3.5f;
unsigned int i = *((unsigned int *)&x);
```

- **e** is the exponent of the float.
- **B** is the bias (127).
- **L** is a constant (1 << 23).
- **m** is the mantissa.

Now my question is:

**Why is the equation correct and where can I read more about this equation?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Floating-Point Encoding

A floating-point number is represented with a sign *s*, an exponent *e*, and a significand *f*. (Some people use the term “mantissa,” but that is a legacy from the days of paper tables of logarithms. “Significand” is preferred for the fraction portion of a floating-point value. Mantissas are logarithmic. Significands are linear.) In binary floating-point, the value represented is + 2<sup>*e*</sup> • *f* or − 2<sup>*e*</sup> • *f*, according to the sign *s*.

Commonly for binary floating-point, the significand is required to be in [1, 2), at least for numbers in the normal range of the format. For encoding, the first bit is separated from the rest, so we may write *f* = 1 + *r*, where 0 ≤ *r* < 1.

In the IEEE 754 basic binary formats, the floating-point number is encoded as a sign bit, some number of exponent bits, and a significand field:

- The sign *s* is encoded with a 0 bit for positive, 1 for negative. Since we are taking a logarithm, the number is presumably positive, and we may ignore the sign bit for current purposes.
- The exponent bits are the actual exponent plus some bias *B*. (For 32-bit format, *B* is 127. For 64-bit, it is 1023.)
- The signifcand field contains the bits of *r*. Since *r* is a fraction, the significand field contains the bits of *r* represented in binary starting after the “binary point.” For example, if *r* is 5/16, it is “.0101000…” in binary, so the significand field contains 0101000… (For 32-bit format, the significand field contains 23 bits. For 64-bit, 52 bits.)

Let *b* the number of bits in the significand field (23 or 52). Let *L* be 2<sup>*b*</sup>.

Then the product of *r* and *L*, *r* • *L*, is an integer equal to the contents of the significand field. In our example, *r* is 5/16, *L* is 2<sup>23</sup> = 8,388,608, and *r* • *L* = 2,621,440. So the significand contains 2,621,440, which is 0x280000.

The equation *I* = (*e* + *B*) • *L* + *m* • *L* attempts to capture this. First, the sign is ignored, since it is zero. Then *e* + *B* is the exponent plus the bias. Multiplying that by *L* shifts it left *b* bits, which puts it in the position of the exponent field of the floating-point encoding. Then adding *r* • *L* adds the value of the significand field (for which I use *r* for “rest of the significand” instead of *m* for “mantissa”).

Thus, the bits that encode 2<sup>*e*</sup> • (1+*r*) as a floating-point number are, when interpreted as a binary integer, (*e* + *B*) • *L* + *r* • *L*.

## More Information

Information about IEEE 754 is in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) and [the IEEE 754 standard](http://grouper.ieee.org/groups/754/). Some previous Stack Overflow answers describing the encoding format at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633163/how-can-a-4-byte-store-such-large-value-of-3-4e38/20633632#20633632) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14001910/what-is-this-denormal-data-about-c/14002396#14002396).

## Aliasing / Reinterpreting Bits

Regarding the code in your question:

```
float x = 3.5f;
unsigned int i = *((unsigned int *)&x);
```

Do not use this code, because its behavior is not defined by the C or C++ standards.

In C, use:

```
#include <string.h>
...
unsigned int i; memcpy(&i, &x, sizeof i);
```

or:

```
unsigned int i = (union { float f; unsigned u; }) { x } .u;
```

In C++, use:

```
#include <cstring>
...
unsigned int i; std::memcpy(&i, &x, sizeof i);
```

These ways are defined to reinterpret the bits of the floating-point encoding as an `unsigned int`. (Of course, they require that a `float` and an `unsigned int` be the same size in the C or C++ implementation you are using.)

Answer (score 2):

As you know floating point numbers are stored in IEEE 754 standard. And bit pattern of the single precision floating points like the following (see details [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format)):

[image]

And the value of the number is calculated based on the following formula:

[image]

Hence, for 32-bit value, the equivalent integer would be `e * L + m`.
Because exponent  is started from (23-rd bit) and the first part is `m`.
As supposed the exponent is stored with `-127`, the expression is transformed to `(e + B)*L + m`.

About the `L` after `m` might be there is an assumption which might not be mentioned in the article.

Moreover, `sign` bit is not considered in this formula.

Comment: I don't really see how this does anything more than restate the question. You haven't related e, L, B or m to anything in your picture.